# Plaid Public Exchange Token Response

Tags: plaid

eg from their site
{
"access_token": "access-sandbox-de3ce8ef-33f8-452c-a685-8671031fc0f6",
"item_id": "M5eVJqLnv3tbzdngLDp9FL5OlDNxlNhlE55op",
"request_id": "Aim3b"
}

My question is what is "item_id" and why it keeps changing on repeated requests. I understand that "access_token" to change on repeated requests.
This is what Plaid documentation says
"item_id - string
The item_id value of the Item associated with the returned access_token"

How what should I treat this Item_Id as? InstitutionID?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `item_id` actually changing across multiple consecutive API requests, or only if you link an account multiple times? It is normal and correct for you to get different `item_ids` if you link the same bank account multiple times. Two linked accounts are considered different items even if they are actually based on the same user credentials at the same institution.

An `item_id` is an identifier associated with an item. It is less sensitive than an access token, because it cannot be used to access any data. So it is used as a safer way of referring to an item across the Plaid API than passing the access token around. For example, webhooks that give information about a change to an item will include an item_id to let you know which item the webhook is about.

Comment: Yes, even if I link same account again and again with same secrets and client id. Even with same public token or different public token. This is my test scenarios. I really appreciate your response. Thank you

Comment: Yes, re-linking the same account is expected to result in different account ids.